# Pass a dictionary value as null to alamofire service ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null, alamofire

I am trying to send a value in dictionary as null as parameter for alamofire post request

```
var time: String?
 var dic = ["aaaa:add,
            "bbbb":bbbb,
            "cccc":cccc,
            "dddd": dddd,
            "eeee":eeee,
            "ffff":ffff,
            "gggg":time] as [String : Any]
```

How can i send variable "time" as "null".

Comment: What exactly does `null` mean?

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: my service only takes the value as null. doenot take parameter as empty string or nil

Comment: I tried giving nil and empty string value, but i am getting error response . Also  i tried with NSnull

Comment: @FaheemRahman Ask your service provider it's not possible in iOS. **null** if used in android in iOS it will be **nil**

Comment: @FaheemRahman pass the value as nil. You will have to make necessar changes in the backend. In IOS you can use nil instead of null.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent of a `null` value is `NSNull`, use the nil coalescing operator to pass an `NSNull` instance if `time` is `nil`.

```
var time: String?
var dic : [String : Any] = ["aaaa":"add",
                            "bbbb":"bbbb",
                            "cccc":"cccc",
                            "dddd": "dddd",
                            "eeee":"eeee",
                            "ffff":"ffff",
                            "gggg":time ?? NSNull()]
```